# Backup Xen VM without snapshot

Tags: xen, xenserver

I have a VM in a small XenServer 6.2 and I would like to back-up it before performing an upgrade. The current storage doesn't have enough space to do a snapshot, so I cannot export it.

Is there any way to "download" a restorable VM image without taking a snapshot?

Stopping the VM is not an issue if required.

Comment: I'n not familiar with XenServer, but I know on ESXi you can access the local disk and just copypasta the entire VM directory. Crude, but would in theory work. To restore just dump the old image back, overwriting the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

To backup a vm, the best way is to export it. It goes also for your old version of xenserver at the time of the question.

attach a nfs storage to your server by

```
xe sr-create type=nfs content-type=backup name-label=na;e_you_want_to_give shared=true device-config:server=ip_address_of_your_server device-config:serverpath=name_of_the_share_on_your_server
```

see where xenserver have mounted it

```
mount
```

uuid of the vm

```
xe vm-list
```

export the vm

```
xe vm-export vm=uuid_of_your_vm filename=path_of_the_share/name_you_want_to_give_to_your_backup.xva
```

[source](https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/346198-how-to-export-vm-in-local-storage-and-then-import-that-vm-in-shared-storage/)

Answer (score -1):

Shutdown the vm and make a copy of the .vhd file. To find that one, use

```
xe vdi-list
```

This will show the sr-uuid and the uuid (which is the vhd name). You might want to check mount to find the sr-uuid path (/run/sr-mount/sr-uuid/uuid.vhd) and then look for the vhd in there.

Also don't forget to backup the metatdate with

```
xe vm-export filename=metadata.bak uuid=8ac95696-... metadata=true
```